# System of 3 differential equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to look whether there exist solutions to a system of 3 differential equations. The differential equations are given by

$$ x' = \dfrac{a}{(1-z)y}$$
$$ y' = \dfrac{b}{(1-x)z}$$
$$ z' = \dfrac{c}{(1-y)x}$$

where all variables are functions of k, derivatives are derivatives with respect to k. a,b, and c are known functions of k.

I actually have never seen a system of differential equations that look like this. Any thoughts on methods how to check whether there exist solutions given initial values?

Comment: What kind of functions are $a,b,c$, could you specify? It may affect the existense of solution. As for the question, are you only interested in the existense of solutions? Or do you need a method to obtain them explicitly?

Comment: Hey Yuriy. Actually I was thinking about pdfs for $a,b,c$ with same support as some CDFs $x,y,z$. I am primarily concerned with the existence of solutions, but once I would get to know that there exists a solution of course I would be interested in methods to obtain it.